# Oracle ZFS chown command not permitted

Tags: nfs, chown, zfs

After successfully mounting the directory (ZFS remote storage) from one of the server, I'm getting an "Operation not permitted" error when I try changing the ownership of the directory. I'm using the following command:
To mount the remote directory:

```
mount -t nfs 10.1.32.33:/dir/temp/tools  /home/materials
```

After mounting the directory, the contents are belongs to nobody:nobody

[image]

I want to change ownership so I can run the installer inside the directory.
I'm using the command below to change ownership but it's not working:

chown -R otm:otm materials/

I can always upload the file to the server without using the ZFS storage, however I want to start making a central installer repository so I don't need to upload the files/installers for future server install. I appreciate your help guys.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

NFS servers by default do not allow root access to files - root is normally mapped to "nobody".

See ["root squash"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_security#Root_squash):

> Root squash[2][3] is a reduction of the access rights for the remote
> superuser (root) when using identity authentication (local user is the
> same as remote user). It is primarily a feature of NFS but may be
> available on other systems as well.
>
> This problem arises when a remote file system is shared by multiple
> users. These users belong to one or multiple groups. In Unix, every
> file and folder normally has separate permissions (read, write,
> execute) for the owner (normally the creator of the file), for the
> group to which the owner belongs, and for the "world" (all other
> users). This allows restriction of read and write access only to the
> authorized users while in general the NFS server must also be
> protected by firewall.
>
> A superuser has more rights than an ordinary user, **being able to
> change the file ownership**, set arbitrary permissions, and access all
> protected content. Even users that do need to have root access to
> individual workstations may not be authorized for the similar actions
> on a shared file system. Root squash reduces rights of the remote
> root, making one no longer superuser. On UNIX like systems, root
> squash option can be turned on and off in /etc/exports file on a
> server side.
>
> After implementing the root squash, the authorized superuser performs
> restricted actions after logging into an NFS server directly and not
> just by mounting the exported NFS folder.

In general, you **DO NOT** want to disable root squash unless you **REALLY** know what you're doing as there are serious security issues you can create if you do that.  And since you didn't even know it exists...

(And that mention of `/etc/exports` is an extremely limited statement that is wrong on many systems - like Solaris.)